# Rename Folder with errors

Tags: vb.net, variables, edit

Okay so i find another option, thats simpler. I want to rename the folder at Destination, but it dosnt work.

```
    Dim Log As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmss"))
    Process.Start("CMD", "/c robocopy.exe " & Source & " " & Destination & "/z /log:C:\Backup\log_" & Log & ".txt")



    Dim Copy2 As String = ("Backup_" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmss"))
    My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameDirectory(Destination, Copy2)
    Process.Start(Copy2) 'öffnet explorer 
    MsgBox("Backup ist vollendet!")
```

Comment: Are you actually asking how to assign a value to a variable?

Comment: [Basically a less well asked duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40345211)

Comment: Are you asking how to find the last '\' in a string and truncate the string there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB - edit FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40345211/vb-edit-folderbrowserdialog1-selectedpath)

Comment: please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after:

```
Dim backupDirectory As String = "C:\Backup\Here"

Dim di As DirectoryInfo = Directory.GetParent(backupDirectory)

Debug.Write(di.FullName)

'Output:
'C:\Backup
```

Comment: please see my answer

Comment: Please do not advise looking for literal backslashes. One needs to use relevant classes from `System.IO` and `System.IO.Path`.

Answer (score 1):

Tricky one! Try this:

```
Destination = "C:\backup"
```

Comment: thats the thing, i need to like remove the last folder out of the destination variable. So this dosnt work

Comment: @bigMre But that is not what you asked.  'edit a varaible' says nothing about parsing and removing elements from a path.

Comment: please see my answer